# A property on finite sequences $1,1,x_2, x_3, \dots, x_{n-1}$ with $x_i \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Consider a finite sequence
$$x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$$
with $n$ odd, all $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ and in particular $x_0 = x_1 = 1$. Furthermore, assume that the number of nonzero $x_i$ is even and $\leq (n+1)/2$.

In dimensions 3 and 5, one only has the sequences $1,1,0$ and $1,1,0,0,0$ respectively. However, from dimension 7 onwards the number of possible sequences increases rapidly.

We say that a sequence is *nice* when for all $I \subsetneq \{0, 1,  \dots, n-1\}$ with $\#I$ odd,  $\exists j \in I$ such that
$$ \# \{ i \in I \mid x_{i-j} = 1\} \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$$
where the index $i-j$ is taken $\text{mod } n$ if necessary.

A few observations:

- If $\#I = 1$, then clearly the condition is met.
- If $I$ is a set for which we can not find a suitable $j$, then the sets $I+1 = \{i+1 \mid i \in I\}$, $I+2$, $\dots$, $I+(n-1)$ do not have a suitable $j$ either.
- By the previous point, it suffices to check sets $I$ with $0 \in I$ and $n-1 \notin I$. There are less to check, but I find this condition useful for computational purposes.

Now, the question:

**Are the only *nice* sequences those of the form $1,1,0,0,\dots,0$ ?**

I've checked this up to $n = 17$ ($n = 19$ will take hours) and found no counterexamples. However, I also can't think of a way to prove they are the only nice sequences.

(suggestions for a better title or better tags are always welcome, I have no idea what domain this belongs to)